# multiple dependent and non-dependent dropdowns in dash python

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am very confused as to how I can have multiple dropdowns using dash. I want to display companies, then based on the company display the product and separately display gender on the on the dropdowns (3 dropdowns in total), the output is just a graph with age and number values.

Here is an example of the data:

```
Company    Product    Gender    Age    Price
---------------------------------------------
Company1   X          Female    25     100
Company1   Y          Male      54     120
Company2   W          Male      18     130
...
```

The code I have right now works with a single dropdown:

```
    app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H1("Web Application Dashboards with Dash", style={'text-align': 'center'}),

    dcc.Dropdown(id="slct_company",
                 options=[
                     {"label": "Company1", "value": "Company1"},
                     {"label": "Company2", "value": "Company2"},
                     {"label": "Company3", "value": "Company3"}
                     
                 ],

                 multi=False,
                 value= 'All',
                 style={'width': "40%"}
                 ),

    html.Div(id='output_container', children=[]),
    html.Br(),

    dcc.Graph(id='Coeff_Analysis', figure={}, style={'width': '150vh', 'height': '90vh'})

])

@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='output_container', component_property='children'),
     Output(component_id='Coeff_Analysis', component_property='figure')],
    [Input(component_id='slct_company', component_property='value')]
)

def update_graph(option_slctd):
    #print(option_slctd)
    #print(type(option_slctd))

    container = "The company chosen by user was: {}".format(option_slctd)

    dff = df.copy()
    if option_slctd == 'All':
        dff = dff
    else:
        dff = dff[dff["Company"] == option_slctd]

    # Plotly Express

    fig = px.scatter(df, x=dff['Age'], y=dff['Price'], color=dff['Company'], marginal_y="violin",
           marginal_x="box", trendline="ols", template="simple_white")

    fig.update_layout(
         title_text="Coefficient per company/product/gender/age",
         title_xanchor="center",
         title_font=dict(size=24),
         title_x=0.5
     )

    return container, fig


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

So my end result is a single dropdown that has as default all companies, and I want to add dropdowns to separate between products of each company and gender while still have the "all" option.

I already have a dictionary with the company key and products, but don't know how to implement.

I have searched and don't understand the other solutions I have found.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 2 callback functions
1 for the the affected drop down and the other is for the graph:

```
@app.callback(
Output('drop2', 'options'),
Output('drop2', 'value'),
[Input('drop1','value')])
def update_dropdown(selected_company):
dff = df[df['Product'] == selected_company]
company_options = [{'label':i,'value':i} for i in dff["Product"].unique()]
return company_options, city_options[0]['value']

@app.callback(
Output('graph', 'figure'),
[Input('drop2', 'value'),
 Input('drop1', 'value')])
 
def update_graph(product,company):

dff = df[df["Product"] == product]
```

then create the figure you want.